# R: trouble reading dates and time

Tags: r, posixct

I have some problems in reading in date and time in a proper way, and I wonder why I get these problems. The problem is only on my windows installation of R. Running the exact same script on my UNIX installation works fine.

Basically, I want to read in a file with data and time as the second column, like this:

```
TrainData[[i]] = read.csv(TrainFiles[i],header=F, colClasses=c(NA,"POSIXct",rep(NA,8)))
    colnames(TrainData[[i]])=c("comp","time","s1","s2","s3","s4","r1","r2","r3","r4")
```

However, only the dates are read, not the times, and my data looks like this:

```
       comp       time  s1  s2  s3  s4  r1 r2 r3 r4
1     1 2009-08-18 711 630  69 600 689 20 40  1
2     5 2009-08-18 725 460 101 705 689 20 40  1
3     6 2009-08-18 711 505  69 678 689 20 40  1
4     1 2009-08-18 705 630  69 600 689 20 40  1
5     2 2009-08-18 734 516 101 671 689 20 40  1
6     3 2009-08-18 743 637  69 595 689 20 40  1
7     4 2009-08-18 730 577 101 633 689 20 40  1
8     2 2009-08-18 721 511 101 674 689 20 40  1
9     3 2009-08-18 747 563 101 642 689 20 40  1
10    4 2009-08-18 716 572 101 636 689 20 40  1
```

Running the exact same cond on UNIX returned both time and dates. 
When I read in another file in the same script, with dates and times in the two first columns, I get the correct format of the date/time:

```
TrainData[[i]]=read.csv(TrainFiles[i],header=F, colClasses=c("POSIXct","POSIXct",NA))
    colnames(TrainData[[i]])=c("start","end","fault")
```

returns

```
                 start                 end fault
1  2010-10-24 04:25:53 2010-10-24 11:22:33     6
2  2010-10-30 12:57:16 2010-11-02 12:29:54     6
3  2010-11-05 10:40:17 2010-11-05 11:59:51     6
4  2010-11-05 17:07:37 2010-11-06 14:30:01     6
5  2010-11-06 23:59:59 2010-11-07 00:14:49     6
6  2010-11-06 23:59:59 2010-11-07 00:14:49     6
7  2010-11-06 23:59:59 2010-11-07 00:14:49     6
8  2010-11-06 23:59:59 2010-11-07 00:14:49     6
9  2010-11-06 23:59:59 2010-11-07 00:14:50     6
10 2010-11-06 23:59:47 2010-11-07 00:14:51     6
```

Actually, I found a solution that works, eventually, but I wonder why I get these problems. 
It appears that my Sys.timezone is set to "Europe/Berlin". If I set this to NA, the times will be read in as well, i.e. using `Sys.setenv(tz=NA)`. If I then run the same code, my data looks like this:

```
   comp                time  s1  s2  s3  s4  r1 r2 r3 r4
1     1 2009-08-18 18:12:00 711 630  69 600 689 20 40  1
2     5 2009-08-18 18:14:27 725 460 101 705 689 20 40  1
3     6 2009-08-18 18:14:31 711 505  69 678 689 20 40  1
4     1 2009-08-18 18:14:43 705 630  69 600 689 20 40  1
5     2 2009-08-18 18:14:47 734 516 101 671 689 20 40  1
6     3 2009-08-18 18:14:51 743 637  69 595 689 20 40  1
7     4 2009-08-18 18:15:00 730 577 101 633 689 20 40  1
8     2 2009-08-18 18:29:33 721 511 101 674 689 20 40  1
9     3 2009-08-18 18:29:37 747 563 101 642 689 20 40  1
10    4 2009-08-18 18:29:45 716 572 101 636 689 20 40  1
```

The other file still get times, but now consistently two hours different.

This is how the csv-files look like (basically, text separated by commas): 
this is my file (basically text separated by commas):

> 1,2009-08-18 18:12:00,711,630,69,600,689,20,40,1
>
> 5,2009-08-18 8:14:27,725,460,101,705,689,20,40,1
>
> 6,2009-08-18 18:14:31,711,505,69,678,689,20,40,1
>
> 1,2009-08-18 18:14:43,705,630,69,600,689,20,40,1
>
> 2,2009-08-18 8:14:47,734,516,101,671,689,20,40,1
>
> 3,2009-08-18 18:14:51,743,637,69,595,689,20,40,1
>
> 4,2009-08-18 8:15:00,730,577,101,633,689,20,40,1
>
> 2,2009-08-18 8:29:33,721,511,101,674,689,20,40,1
>
> 3,2009-08-18 8:29:37,747,563,101,642,689,20,40,1
>
> 4,2009-08-18 8:29:45,716,572,101,636,689,20,40,1

Why am I having these problems with reading in the times? I would expect that it is not correct to use tz=NA, but this is the only way I found to work. Can anyone help me figure out why the times are ignored when tz = "Europe/Berlin"? 
Is it generally adviced to put tz=NA when reading files like this? Even if this seems to work in reading in the times, the tz="NA" results in warning messages when I later want to work with the data:

```
Warning message:
In as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : unknown timezone 'NA'
```

Can anyone help me explain the differences I get?

Comment: It would be helpful to add a few lines of your csv file.

Comment: OK, this is my file (basically text separated by commas): 1,2009-08-18 18:12:00,711,630,69,600,689,20,40,1
5,2009-08-18 8:14:27,725,460,101,705,689,20,40,1
6,2009-08-18 18:14:31,711,505,69,678,689,20,40,1
1,2009-08-18 18:14:43,705,630,69,600,689,20,40,1
2,2009-08-18 8:14:47,734,516,101,671,689,20,40,1
3,2009-08-18 18:14:51,743,637,69,595,689,20,40,1
4,2009-08-18 8:15:00,730,577,101,633,689,20,40,1
2,2009-08-18 8:29:33,721,511,101,674,689,20,40,1
3,2009-08-18 8:29:37,747,563,101,642,689,20,40,1
4,2009-08-18 8:29:45,716,572,101,636,689,20,40,1

Comment: Could you please include that into the question body?